# Update object within object using Redux action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm making a kind of twitter-style clone using React and Redux. I currently have an object of posts ("lings"), that each contain a nested object of replies. They look like this:

```
  {
    id: 5,
    userName: "Gordon Maloney",
    lingBody: "this is a ling",
    lingRepliesObj: [
      {
        replyId: 0,
        replyBody: "this is a reply",
      },
      {
        replyId: 1,
        replyBody: "this is a second reply",
      },
    ],
  },
```

I'm trying to build an action that allows users to add a reply, by adding to that nested object. The action pushes the ID of the post being replied to, and then the reply itself - when I console log them, it comes through fine, but I just cannot for the life of me work out:~

a) how to be adding to the right item in the object - it's being passed to the *action* as "parentId" - but I can't work out how to get it from there into the action reducer

b) I am also definitely doing something wrong trying to add the action payload into the array itself.

The action reducer looks like this (currently just pushing the array index of 5 arbitrarily, but that's what I'm wanting to replace with the parentId)

```
    case ActionTypes.POST_REPLY:
      console.log(...state.lings[5].lingRepliesObj);
      console.log(action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        lings: [...state.lings[5].lingRepliesObj, {...action.payload}],
      };
```

And the action itself like this:

```
export const postReply = (values) => {
  console.log("You posted a new reply: ", values);
  return {
    type: "POST_REPLY",
    payload: {
      replyId: "new-id",
      replyAuthor: "reply tester",
      replyType: "correction",
      correctionBody: values.replyCorrection,
      replyBody: values.replyReply,
    },
  };
};
```

Am I even close?

My GitHub for it is here: https://github.com/gordonmaloney/Lingr and the relevant files are:
src/components/actions/newReplyAction
src/components/reducers/lings
src/components/LingReply

Comment: use immer instead of doing this manually

Comment: hadn't come across Immer but looking at the documentation now it looks like just what I'm after - thanks!

Comment: Please use the official Redux Toolkit which includes immer for reducers automatically and if the officially recommended way of writing Redux for two years by now. You might have followed an outdated tutorial.
https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux